# Django - error while saving an object in `TabularInline` while the primary key is a string and is readonly

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have the following models:

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Child(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The `Child` model has a primary key (ID) of type `string`.

Now I'm trying to display the children in a `TabularInline` inline inside the `Parent` admin form and I want the ID field to be readonly:

```py
class ChildMemberLinkAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Child
    extra = 0
    fields = ("id", "name")
    readonly_fields = ("id",)

@admin.register(Parent)
class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ("name",)

    inlines = (ChildMemberLinkAdmin,)
```

I created a parent and a child in Django Shell, and verified each has an ID and name. They're displayed correctly in Django Admin. However, when I click the `Save` button in the `Parent` form (even without changing anything) I get an error "Please correct the errors below.". When I debugged it I noticed that child's `id` is somehow missing, which is weird because my `Child` instance already has an ID which is displayed as readonly in the `TabularInline` in the form.

When I remove `id` from the `ChildMemberLinkAdmin.readonly_fields` everything works correctly.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

I'm using the latest Django version: 3.2